# Selenium Xpath - need the grand child of the matching elements

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath

im using below xpath to get the handle of grand child elements:

**Xpath:**

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@id,'contact.fieldControl-option-set-select')][2]"))
```

**Dom:**

```
<div id="id-6789e999-a812-4ae0-8c39-a736a4ca4a19-19-contact.fieldControl-option-set-select" data-id="contact.fieldControl-option-set-select-container" role="presentation" class="dm bp hh ab z w flexbox">
    <select id="id-6789e999-a812-4ae0-8c39-a736a4ca4a19-19-preferredcontactmethodcode-preferredcontactmethodcode.fieldControl-option-set-select" aria-label="Preferred Method of Contact" title="Preferred Method of Contact" data-id="preferredcontactmethodcode.fieldControl-option-set-select" describedbyelementid="" class="so sp sq ">
        <option id="id-6789e999-a812-4ae0-8c39-a736a4ca4a19-19-contact.fieldControl-option-set-select" value="-1" class="sn qa ">---</option>
        <option id="id-6789e999-a812-4ae0-8c39-a736a4ca4a19-19-contact.fieldControl-option-set-select" value="1" class="sn qa "">Any</option>
        <option id="id-6789e999-a812-4ae0-8c39-a736a4ca4a19-19-contact.fieldControl-option-set-select" value="2" class="sn qa ">Email</option>
        <option id="id-6789e999-a812-4ae0-8c39-a736a4ca4a19-19-contact.fieldControl-option-set-select" value="3" class="sn qa ">Phone</option>
        <option id="id-6789e999-a812-4ae0-8c39-a736a4ca4a19-19-contact.fieldControl-option-set-select" value="4" class="sn qa ">Fax</option>
        <option id="id-6789e999-a812-4ae0-8c39-a736a4ca4a19-19-contact.fieldControl-option-set-select" value="5" class="sn qa ">Letter</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Note:
since my xpath matches div/select/options. im just looking for **option** elements here.

show me the effective and easiest way

Comment: according to XPath all `option/@id` contains  `contact.fieldControl-option-set-select` then you want to select all. right?

Comment: Even though an element has an ID, in case like this the ID is really complex and may not be worth using. I would look at other attributes that are available, e.g. title.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should use XPaths any deeper than the `select` element. Selenium Wedriver provides an abstraction layer over the "select"->"option" blocks and gives you a nice way to control options (ref: [`SelectElement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement.htm)):

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

// select the drop down list
var education = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("select[title='Preferred Method of Contact']"));

// create select element object 
var selectElement = new SelectElement(education);
```

Then you can use `selectElement` to select options by text, value or index. As well as retrieve all available options or a desired one.

Comment: In this case I would ignore the complex ID and just use `title="Preferred Method of Contact"`, e.g. `By.CssSelector("select[title='Preferred Method of Contact']")`. I like to be able to "read" my selectors whenever possible.

Comment: @alecxe - Thanks it works.. what is the replacement method of contains text() in CSS Selectors ? . I have other element whose title attributes are not available in such places i want to use contains method.

Comment: @JeffC in some places we wont have title attributes. how do deal with is complex id? first of id will dynamic and second part will be fixed value. what will be your approach ?

Comment: I would first look for some other attribute (like title) that I can use. If I can't find that, then I would do a partial ID match... but that wasn't your question. Your question was about a specific element. If you want a more broadly applicable answer, you need to provide more context to the question. Show different examples, some with title, some without, etc. Then you will get a better answer to your question.

Comment: For a partial match using CSS selectors, you would use one of three options given the example HTML <option id="123456789" ...>: 1. starts with `select[id^='123']`, 2. ends with `select[id$='789']`, 3. contains `select[id*='456']`. See [this CSS reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview) for more info. In your specific case, you could use `select[id$='preferredcontactmethodcode-preferredcontactmethodcode.fieldControl-option-set-select']` and then get the OPTIONs using the `SelectElement` class.

Answer (score 0):

use this for grand child :

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@id,'contact.fieldControl-option-set-select')]/*/*[contains(@id,'contact.fieldControl-option-set-select')]"))
```